# An election for election official? or Am i interpreting it the wrong way?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

In this HeadLine by NYtimes:

["Every election denier who sought to become the top election official in a critical battleground state lost at the polls."](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/11/12/us/politics/jim-marchant-nevada.html)

seems like there is an election to become an election official, is that so?

I also read the source, but it did not clarify my doubts

Comment: It's a confusing utterance, clumsily phrased. But I assume "the top election official" simply refers to the "most important" elected position in any given US State during the current mid-term elections (being a Brit, I don't know the details, but presumably in some States that's a delegate to the House of Representatives, in others, the Senate). According to NYT, any candidates in "borderline" States who claimed that the *previous* (presidential) election was fraudulent (all Republicans, obviously) ***lost*** in the current mid-term elections.

Comment: This question would have been better asked on [politics.se]  @fumblefingers.  No it means what it says.  In most states of the USA the senior election official is elected (as are judges, police chiefs, city sanitation officials etc)

Comment: @JamesK: Yes, it was obvious immediately after I posted my comment (when I saw your answer) that I'd got the wrong end of the stick there. But I thought it made sense to leave it, if only because of the first sentence (which imho is still perfectly true, even if what follows *isn't*). Besides which, at the end of the day, I think that for a learner to actually *know* exactly what this text means isn't worth anywhere near as much as realising that even perfectly competent native speakers won't necessarily understand it (so by implication, *it's not very important*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "what this text means isn't worth anywhere near as much as realising that even perfectly competent native speakers won't necessarily understand it" I appreciate that idea of you

Comment: guerdoosinfu: Thank you for the acknowledgement. I feel this is an area where the normal effect of Stack Exchange voting can be misleading. @JamesK's answer gets upvotes because it's undeniably *true*, but until I just added my own upvote, your question actually had a *negative* net vote total. It's a bit bizarre that in some US states, people get to vote on who should count the votes, even though many of those voters are convinced the entire electoral system is corrupt anyway. But at time of asking, you weren't to know this question is more about culture/politics than language itself.

Comment: @FumbleFinger, "It's a bit bizarre that in some US states, people get to vote on who should count the votes" I totally agree and that confuses the reading for someone not fluent yet in English. Also please check this source: "https://www.ncsbe.gov/about-elections/get-involved-elections/become-election-official#:~:text=To%20serve%20as%20an%20election,status%20with%20the%20Voter%20Search". seems like the trem  "election official" is more like a general term, not specific to one case or Am I tripping out?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In many states of USA, elections are overseen by an official called the "[Secretary of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_of_state_(U.S._state_government))", and in 35 of the 50 states, this position is elected (for a term of two or four years).  The Secretary of State is the chief clerk of the state, the keeper of records, and the chief election official (although many delegate the actual day-to-day planning, organisation, and running of the election to an appointed supervisor of election and their team).

Nevertheless, in most states, the Secretary of State holds ultimate responsibility for financial arrangements, the enforcement of electoral law and regulation, and the integrity of the vote.

Comment: This is a political answer, because this is a political question.

Comment: you have just answered my question very properly. To me the confusion began when I looked up the term election official and found this: "https://www.ncsbe.gov/about-elections/get-involved-elections/become-election-official#:~:text=To%20serve%20as%20an%20election,status%20with%20the%20Voter%20Search." in it there is some qualification to become ellection official which one is to be at least 17 years old and in good academic standing, so secretary of state didn't cross my mind that way I would never thought a voting for the position would be necessary